# Trying to submit a JSON body in an HTTP request gives java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, json, httpurlconnection

I am trying to test an API on an Android application. When I call an action on postman with a raw JSON body of `"some string"`, I get a proper response. However, when I try to call the same action on Android, I get a `java.io.FileNotFoundException`

```
URL url = new URL("my_correct_url");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
os.write("some text".getBytes());
os.close();

// Following line gives: java.io.FileNotFoundException
InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

Could you help me spot the problem?

The action code I am calling is as follows:

```
// This is an ASP.NET Core action
[HttpPost]
[Route("test1")]
public string Test([FromBody] string s)
{
    return "test output: " + s;
}
```

Comment: `// Following line gives: java.io.FileNotFoundException
InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream(); ` Sorry but i do not believe that. It must be another line.

Comment: @blackapps Stacktrace points to that exact line. I honestly don't know what causes this. The full error code is "java.io.FileNotFoundException: "my_correct_url" "

Comment: Then use a correct url. You can post a fake url but show how it is build up as now nobody knows what you are doing.

Comment: Url is correct. That is not the problem. In postman, everything works. I am not trying to hide anything. I have a genuine problem. I have 2 different API calls. One takes no argument and returns a string. This one works perfectly fine (just remove from setDoInput to os.close). The second API call takes a string as input and gives a string as output. This second one gives this unnatural exception. I showed you the exact backend code as well.

Comment: `Url is correct. That is not the problem. ` Maybe it is. Is it a http url on an Android 10 device?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222834/discussion-between-m-azyoksul-and-blackapps).

Answer (score 0):

TIL, `some text` is not valid JSON, `"some text"` is. So changing the following line

```
os.write("some text".getBytes());
```

to

```
os.write("\"some text\"".getBytes());
```

solved my problem.